# Vertical gap between 2 legends in ggplot2/ vertical gap between 2 keys in the same legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

This is a follow up query to this query:
[How to do expand_limits to a factor and keep the existing color scheme and display the na.value box in the legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73189315/how-to-do-expand-limits-to-a-factor-and-keep-the-existing-color-scheme-and-displ/73189811#73189811)

Here is the output which I am trying to modify.

[image: Sample-Image]

It was made using this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
df  <- data.frame(x = sample(c("A", "B","C", "D"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                  y = as.factor(sample(c("North", "South", "West", NA), 100, replace = TRUE)))

ggplot(df) +
  aes(x, fill = y, color ="") +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values  = c("red",
                                "green",
                                "blue"),
                    na.value = "black" )+
  scale_color_manual(labels="Special value",values="black")+
 guides(fill = guide_legend(order=1),color = guide_legend(title = "", order=2,override.aes = list(fill="white")))
```

I wish to make the 2 legends appear as if they were levels of ***one*** legend.

To do this I wish to make the space between the 2 legends = the space between the keys in the legend on top.

My queries are:

1. How do I find out how much space is there by ***default*** between  the keys in the legend on top.
2. How do I then modify the space between 2 legends to be equal to the answer of 1.

My research so far:
I think I need theme(legend.spacing.y) for the ***second*** legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I understand the following from https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/main/R/theme-defaults.r :

- The space between two legends (`legend.spacing`) is 11 pts
- The space between two keys should be 0.5 pt (`base_rect_size`)
- The margin around each legend is 5.5 pts (`legend.margin`)
- `legend.title` size is 11 pts, we will discuss that later.

So we have 28 pts between the keys of our two legends. Let's try to plot that (I added `legend.key` in the theme in order to visualize the `base_rect_size`) :

```
ggplot(df) +
  aes(x, fill = y, color ="") +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values  = c("red",
                                "green",
                                "blue"),
                    na.value = "black" )+
  scale_color_manual(labels="Special value",values="black")+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(order=1),color = guide_legend(title = "Test", order=2,override.aes = list(fill="white"))) +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(size = unit(0.5, 'pt'), color = "purple"),
        legend.margin =  margin(-28,0,0,0,unit="pt"))
```

[image]

We can see that there is a problem with the title, fortunately we can get rid of it with `title=NULL` in `guides`. By removing it the space between the keys drops to 17 pts.

```
ggplot(df) +
  aes(x, fill = y, color ="") +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values  = c("red",
                                "green",
                                "blue"),
                    na.value = "black" )+
  scale_color_manual(labels="Special value",values="black")+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(order=1),color = guide_legend(title = NULL, order=2,override.aes = list(fill="white"))) +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(size = unit(0.5, 'pt'), color = "purple"),
        legend.margin =  margin(-17,0,0,0,unit="pt"))
```

[image]

Finally, we want to recreate the 0.5pt space between our keys :

```
ggplot(df) +
  aes(x, fill = y, color ="") +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values  = c("red",
                                "green",
                                "blue"),
                    na.value = "black" )+
  scale_color_manual(labels="Special value",values="black")+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(order=1),color = guide_legend(title = NULL, order=2,override.aes = list(fill="white"))) +
  theme(legend.margin =  margin(-16.5,0,0,0,unit="pt"))
```

[image]

Comment: So we have 28 pts between the keys of our two legends. Should the legend.margin be counted 2 times in this computation since there are 2 legends with a margin around each? What happens when there are 3 legends ? How do we tell the software that we may need different spacing around each legend ?

Comment: The `legend.margin` should not be counted two times otherwise the legends would overlap severly. 


The idea of the `legend.margin =  margin(-16.5,0,0,0,unit="pt")` is to crop the top margin of each legend in order to make them overlap "nicely" by removing the top margin. We could obviously go with `legend.margin =  margin(-5.5,0,-11,0,unit="pt")` and it would produce more or less the same result (croping top and bottom margins).

Regarding the case with more than 2 legends I have no idea.

Comment: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/main/R/guide-legend.r#L338 says that the default vertical gap is half of the default fontsize (11) in pts which would be 5.5 pts.  I wish to know how you got -The space between two keys should be 0.5 pt (base_rect_size).